# Java: In Eclipse, is it possible to show an instance variable's name while debugging one of it's methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, instance-variables

I've pasted the classes relevant to my question below.  `vis2` is an instantiated version of the `Connect2` class.  When debugging, if I'm in the `Connect` class, and then jump into the `vis2.setURL(String url)` method, `this` is listed in the `Variables`view.  The value for `this` is listed as `Connect2 (id=22)`.

Is it possible to have Eclipse show WHICH instance of `Connect2` `this` is describing (in this case `vis2`)? Thanks in advance.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
  public static main(String[] args) {
    Connect connect = new Connect();
    connect.findLocid();  
  }
}
```

Connect.java

```
public class Connect {
  public void findLocid(){
    Connect2 vis2 = new Connect2();
     vis2.setURL("Https://www.someurl.com");
     vis2.execute();
  }
}
```

Connect2.java

```
public class Connect2 {
  private String url;
  public Connect3 me;

  public void execute() {
    me = new Connect3(this.url);
    me.connect();
  }

  public void setURL(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Objects don't have names in Java... `id=22` *is* Eclipse trying to show you which object it is.

Comment: A variable name is just a human-friendly identifier for object references, the names you see in a debugger are only there due to "debug information" being compiled into the class files.  As far as I know, what you want is impossible.  The names you see in a debugger are named references to objects on a given object (graph of names), when you step in that method, you're looking at the root of that graph as "this", the debugger doesn't know anything about who holds refs to "this".  There could be 1,000 variables all holding a reference to "this" with different names, which one would it show?

Comment: You could add a name String to your object for debugging purposes

Comment: @Alex but aren't the actual containers for the variables identified by a Id?  So wouldn't the "this" for one instance have a different Id than the "this" for another instance of the constructor?  On that note, how come each time I debug my application, the variables are assigned completely different Id's?  Does't the application more or less run in a logical cause and effect manner (excluding debugging challenges when running multiple threads at one time)?

Comment: @immibis thanks.  How come the id for a variable changes each time I run or debug?  I'd have assumed that being a cause/effect series of logical progressions, the ID's would be assigned the same each time provided nothing has changed.  How does it choose an ID for a variable?  Is it based on available resources?

Comment: @k_g this sounds like it might be useful. Can you explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could fix this problem is to add a `name` variable to each of your classes. For example, `Connect2` could be modified as such:

```
public class Connect2 {
    private String url;
    public String name;
    public Connect3 me;
    public Connect2(String name) {// and the rest of your arguments
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void execute() {
        me = new Connect3(this.url);
        me.connect();
    }
    public void setURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the name as follows.

```
Connect2 <variable name> = new Connect2(<variable name>);//+ the rest of your arguments
```

Then you can easily find the value of the name variable.